# Cant understand my syntax mistake in MySQL CREATE FUNCTION

Tags: mysql, sql, function

This is my code and I can not find the mistake! I am trying to create a function that multiplies a value to de input parameter and returns that result! It should not be that difficult but I am not finding my sintaxt mistake

```
CREATE FUNCTION `Costotramite` (monto INT)
    RETURNS INTEGER
    BEGIN
        NO SQL
        DECLARE porcentaje FLOAT;
        SET porcentaje = 0.1;
        DECLARE CostoLicitacion INTEGER;
        SET CostoLicitacion= (monto * porcentaje);
        RETURN CostoLicitacion;
    END
```

The mistake says: error code 1064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DECLARE` has to be before the code.

I also changed it tio deterministic

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION `Costotramite` (monto INT)
> RETURNS INTEGER
> DETERMINISTIC
> BEGIN
>
>   DECLARE porcentaje FLOAT;
>   DECLARE CostoLicitacion INTEGER;
>   SET porcentaje = 0.1;
>   SET CostoLicitacion= (monto * porcentaje);
>   RETURN CostoLicitacion;
> END
> ```

> ```
> SELECT Costotramite(1000)
> ```
>
> ```
> | Costotramite(1000) |
> | -----------------: |
> |                100 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36e3514e5f5828ea13f04c93c6898708)*

Comment: Thank you! Now it works, but I wonder how to make that work as a script. It does perfectly work when you choose "create function" but when you run that code as a regular script it still says there is a syntax error

Comment: Sql has no declare in mysql, but you can make a single sql statement out if it